# Automatically set foreign key in grandchild table in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Say i have the following objects

```
public class MyParent {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyChild {
    public long ParentId;
    public virtual Parent Parent;
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyGrandChild{
    public long ParentChildId;
    public virtual MyChild ParentChild;
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now MyParent is the top-level object, is have a child of MyChild, and MyChild has a child of MyGrandChild.

In the tables that are created, i get

```
MyParent
--Id
--Name

MyChild
-- ParentId
-- Id
-- Name

MyGrandChild
-- ParentChildId
-- Id
-- Name
```

Now it would be very useful to have the foreign key for MyParent in the MyGrandChild table.

I have tried by changing the MyGrandChild object to this

```
public class MyGrandChild{
    public long ParentId;
    public virtual MyParent Parent;
    public long ParentChildId;
    public virtual MyChild ParentChild;
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But an error was thrown about cascase delting, and i had to add the following fluentAPI.

```
modelBuilder<MyGrandChild>()    
    .HasRequired(e => e.Parent)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Now this works, but it forces my to manually have to set the .Parent property on MyGrandChild.

Is there a way of telling entity framework that i want to store a parent parent foreign key and have it set it manually?

Comment: When you say "Now it would be very useful to have the foreign key for MyParent in the MyGrandChild table." why do you mean? why would it be useful? could you not just go MyGrandChild.Parent.Id when you need that property?

Comment: You have created a completely new unrelated relationship, there is nothing that constrains `MyGrandChild.Parent` to the same entity as `MyGrandChild.ParentChild.Parent`. However I don't see the value to this property at all you could just access `MyGrandChild.ParentChild.Parent`.